# formatting a pre block to remove the first indent after Ajax has inserted data into a html code block?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I usually use the below snippet to remove the first indent from my < pre >< code > blocks which works fine.

However im using an Ajax call to populate the html of the code block, which when completes it doesnt format anymore, ive tried to put the pre formatting code after the result is populated too but it still comes out with the large indent on the first line

I also tried to format the data.result with, which didn't work either

```
var pattern = data.result.match(/\s*\n[\t\s]*/);
results.html(data.result.replace(new RegExp(pattern, "g"),'\n'));
```

here is the code:

```
<script>
    $("pre").each(function(){
        var html = $(this).html();
        var pattern = html.match(/\s*\n[\t\s]*/);
        $(this).html(html.replace(new RegExp(pattern, "g"),'\n'));
    });
    var waiting = $('#waiting').hide()
    {% if task_id %}
        var task_id = "{{ task_id }}";
        var results = $('#results');

        get_task_info(task_id);

        function get_task_info(task_id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '/monitoring/get_task_info/'+task_id,
                data: {'task_id': task_id},
                success: function (data) {
                    results.html('');
                    if (data.state == 'PENDING') {
                        waiting.show();
                    }
                    else if(data.state == 'SUCCESS'){
                        waiting.hide();
                        results.html(data.result);
                        $("pre").each(function(){
                            var html = $(this).html();
                            var pattern = html.match(/\s*\n[\t\s]*/);
                            $(this).html(html.replace(new RegExp(pattern, "g"),'\n'));
                        });
                    }
                    if (data.state != 'SUCCESS') {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            get_task_info(task_id)
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    results.html("Error!");
                }
            });
        }
    {% endif %}
</script>
```

EDIT: JS Fiddle Here https://jsfiddle.net/ajwill0/ty7s39ko/2/

oddly enough, in the fiddle neither option works, I have the large indent where there is supposed to be none...

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with your problem so we can reproduce it? If I were you, I would create a JSFiddle where I would have an example where your pre is nicely configured, so we would know what your expectation is and also, another example would be present on the JSFiddle which would not work. You can simulate in your Fiddle the AJAX call via Jest or some custom setTimeout code.

Comment: ive added a fiddle, oddly enough neither option works either rendered html or insertion via java I have the large indent

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if I replace your `pre` block with a `div` block, the extra space on the left side vanishes!

Comment: Just use `pre { 

white-space: pre-line;

}`  in css and see if that works . here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/mfpnvu59/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the actual problem is white-space displayed between the end of `pre` tag and start of `code` tag

**Option 1**: css as mentioned by @Swati in comment

**Option 2**: Edit HTML and remove any white-spaces

e.g.

```
<pre><code>This is page rendered informatiom</code></pre>

<pre id="output_block"><code id="results"></code></pre>
```

JsFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lar916t0/1/

If you are not allowed/able to edit HTML, you need to achieve the same with JavaScript